# I keep getting a white picture in this lens distortion correction program

Tags: python, image, image-processing

I want to write a code that corrects the distortion and also helps defish a fisheye image.
I found a pseudocode for it here and I have tried to stick to it:
http://www.tannerhelland.com/4743/simple-algorithm-correcting-lens-distortion/

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np 

im = Image.open('myimage.png')
img = Image.new("RGB",(512,512),'green')
im = im.convert("RGB")

pix_val = im.load()

pix_valNew = img.load()

width, height = im.size

strength = 1.5
zoom = 1.0


halfWidth = width/2
halfHeight = height/2
theta = -1
if strength == 0:
    strength = 0.00001
correctionRadius = ((width**2 + height**2)/strength)**0.5
for x in range(512):
    for y in range(512):

        newX = x - halfWidth
        newY = y - halfHeight

        distance = (newX**2 + newY**2)**0.5
        r = distance/correctionRadius

        if r == 0:
            theta = 1
        else:
            theta = np.arctan(r)/r
        sourceX = (int)(halfWidth + theta * newX * zoom)
        sourceY = (int)(halfHeight + theta * newY * zoom)
        pix_valNew[x,y] = pix_val[sourceX,sourceY]

img.show()
```

I keep getting an image that is completely white and I am not able to troubleshoot it because I am completely new to it.

512x512 is the resolution of the image i want to "de-fish". 
The logic as far as I understand is to find the location of a particular pixel in 
the fisheye image and map it on its corresponding location in t he normal image

Someone asked for the pseudocode for which I did put the link but I am pasting it here as well. It is as Follows:
input:
    strength as floating point >= 0.  0 = no change, high numbers equal stronger correction.
    zoom as floating point >= 1.  (1 = no change in zoom)

algorithm:

```
set halfWidth = imageWidth / 2
set halfHeight = imageHeight / 2

if strength = 0 then strength = 0.00001
set correctionRadius = squareroot(imageWidth ^ 2 + imageHeight ^ 2) / strength

for each pixel (x,y) in destinationImage
    set newX = x - halfWidth
    set newY = y - halfHeight

    set distance = squareroot(newX ^ 2 + newY ^ 2)
    set r = distance / correctionRadius

    if r = 0 then
        set theta = 1
    else
        set theta = arctangent(r) / r

    set sourceX = halfWidth + theta * newX * zoom
    set sourceY = halfHeight + theta * newY * zoom

    set color of pixel (x, y) to color of source image pixel at (sourceX, sourceY)
```

Any form of help will be very much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. You should consider updating your post to include the pseudo-code.

Comment: Is your 'myimage.png' a 512x512 image?

Comment: Have you debugged the values of your variables? To find out at which point they diverge from your expectations?

Comment: @Cris "Lense" is [generally considered to be a misspelling](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/lense).

Comment: @LightnessRacesBY-SA3.0: I made a typo while fixing a typo. Thanks!

Comment: @JohnAnderson Yes it is the resolution of the image i want to "de-fish"

Comment: I don't have any fish-eye pics, but your code seems to work as expected for me. Do you always get a white screen, regardless of the input image used?

Comment: @JohnAnderson I am working with pictures of the night sky. Those are ending up being all white only . But after I changed the input image to a fisheye image of a city's skyline, i did get a few pixel values which were not white but before the loops could get executed, I got "          File "E:\fullpath of my code\extracting pixel values from image.py", line 40, in <module>
    pix_valNew[x,y] = pix_val[sourceX,sourceY]
IndexError: image index out of range     "

Answer (score 0):

It appears that under some combinations of inputs, illegal indices for the source image are being calculated. A simple fix is to replace

```
pix_valNew[x,y] = pix_val[sourceX,sourceY]
```

with:

```
    try:
        pix_valNew[x,y] = pix_val[sourceX,sourceY]
    except IndexError:
        print('IndexError', x, y, sourceX, sourceY)
        pix_valNew[x, y] = (0, 0, 0)
```

Also, just noticed that a line of your code:

```
correctionRadius = ((width**2 + height**2)/strength)**0.5
```

should be:

```
correctionRadius = ((width**2 + height**2)**0.5)/strength
```

Comment: sorry but it is still a white image

Comment: If you set `strength` to 1 and `zoom` to 1, then the code should just duplicate the original image. Does that happen for you?

Comment: Oops, I meant strength of zero should give the same image.

Comment: Added a note about ab incorrect line of code in my answer, but I doubt that it has any significant effect.

Comment: No. Strength zero and zoom one just gives me a black vertical line, with a small break in between, not wider than a couple of pixels that starts at (0,0) and goes all the way down

Comment: Could you provide one of the images that you are working with?

Comment: I can only guess that there is something odd about your images. Have you tried your code with some unrelated image?

Comment: Yes. I have tried many images. They do not work that well. Some are over three channels R,G and B so they throw an error or some other error keeps coming up. I am wanting to try openCV, some sites mentioned that the lens can be calibrated and the distortion can be corrected